# Show that $(C^1)^\perp =\{ 0\}$ in the inner product space of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, orthogonality

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $195,$ it is asked that

> Let $C$ be the space of all continuous function in the interval
> $0\leq t \leq 1$ with the inner product defined as
> $$(f,g) = \int_0^1 f(t) g(t)dt.$$ If $C^1$ denotes the subspace of all continuous
> differentiable functions, show that $(C^1)^\perp =\{ 0\}$.

Since I'm dealing with differentiable functions, I thought using integration by parts might help, and I got
$$f(1)G(1)  = f(0)G(0) + \int_0^1 f'(t)G(t) dt, $$
where $G' = g $, but it didn't give me anything useful, as far as I see.

**Edit:**

This question is asked in *abstract* linear algebra book, and I have only taken freshman year Calculus courses about functional analysis, so I would appreciate if you give your answer according to this fact.

Comment: I think you meant to write $0\leq t\leq 1$? Or more clearly, just $[0,1]$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I edited, yes $[0,1]$

Comment: Have you heard of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: The title needs changing; I'll do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $f\in C,$ with $\int_0^1 f(x)g(x)\, dx = 0$ for all $g\in C^1.$ Define $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt.$ Observe $F(1)=0,$ simply because $F(1)=\int_0^1 f(t)\, dt = \int_0^1 f(t)\cdot 1\, dt.$

Let's integrate by parts as you were doing. We get, for all $g\in C^1,$

$$0=\int_0^1 f(t)g(t)\,dt = F(1)g(1)-F(0)g(0) - \int_0^1 F(t)g'(t)\,dt.$$

Because $F(0)=0=F(1),$ we obtain

$$\tag 1 \int_0^1 F(t)g'(t)\,dt=0 \text { for all } g\in C^1.$$

One $g$ we can try in $(1)$ is $g(x) = \int_0^x F(t)\,dt,$ a nice $C^1$ function. Since $g'(x) = F(x)$ by the FTC, we obtain

$$\int_0^1 F(t)^2\,dt = 0.$$

Because $F$ is continuous, the last equality implies $F\equiv 0.$ Therefore $F'(x) = f(x)=0$ for all $x.$

Comment: I'm not able to see how $F(1) = 0$

Comment: @onurcanbektas   Read the first paragraph again and note the function $1$ is in $C^1.$

Comment: Wow, this is really a good work, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

By Stone-Weierstrass we have a sequence $(f_n)$ of polynomials converging uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. We have:

$$\int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)|^2 dx \to 0$$

But:

$$\int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)|^2 dx = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2dx + \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2 dx - 2\int_0^1 f(x) f_n(x) dx = \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx + \int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2 dx \to 2 \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2dx$$

Therefore $\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx = 0$ and by continuity, $f^2$ is the zero function (i.e. $f$ is the zero function)

Comment: How do you get that $\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx = 0$? Doesn't your last line imply that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 |f_n(x)|^2dx\to \int_0^1 |f(x)|^2dx$, as expected by dominated convergence?

Comment: Is $f \in (C^1)^\perp ?$

Comment: @onurcanbektas yes.

Comment: @Mark compare the two limits of $\int |f-f_n|^2$

Comment: @Mark no need for DCT. Just uniform convergence stuff.

Comment: Then where did you use the fact that $f \in (C^1)^\perp$ ?

Comment: @Cauchy what is DCT ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas general way to commute limits and integrals

Comment: From what I'm understanding, your proof shows that every continuos function in $[0,1]$ is zero function.

Comment: @onurcanbektas I used it in $\int f f_n = 0$. Please carefully read the equations following "but"..

Comment: Is $f_n$ continuously differentiable ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas it's a polynomial!

Comment: but $f_n$ is a specific polynomial, it is not an arbitrary function in $C^1$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas well I don't know what to tell you

Comment: :D :D See my edit please.

Answer (score 2):

You can show it by an indirect proof:

Assume there is an $f \in C \cap (C¹)^{\perp}$ with $f(t_+) \neq 0$ for an $t_+ \in [0,1]$.

You can assume that $f(t_+) \gt 0$ (otherwise take $(-f)$ as function):
$$f(t_+)>0$$

$f$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$ there is an interval $I$ with a positive length $d>0$ and $t_+ \in I$ such that:
$$f(t) > \epsilon > 0 \mbox{ for all } t \in I$$
Now, choose another smaller interval $I_0 \subset I$ with $t_+ \in I_0$ and length $\frac{d}{2}$ and a function $g \in C¹$ with $g \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$, $g(t) = 1$ on $I_0$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $x \notin I$. So, you get
$$(f,g) = \int_0^1f(t)g(t)\,dt = \int_{I}f(t)g(t)\,dt \geq \int_{I_0}\epsilon \,dt = \epsilon\frac{d}{2} \gt 0$$

**This is a contradiction** to $f \in (C¹)^{\perp}$.
So, $f(t) = 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I haven't competed reading your proof, but If you result is that $f$ cannot be in $(C^1)^\perp$, then it implies that the intersection $C \cap (C^1)^\perp = \{ \}$.

Comment: It shows, that the only function in $C \cap (C^1)^{\perp}$ is the zero function. Besides this, $(0,h) = 0$ for all $h \in C^1$. So, $0 \in C \cap (C^1)^{\perp}$.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake, since $f\perp g$ does not imply $|f|\perp g.$

Comment: @zhw: right ... i use only $f \perp g \rightarrow -f \perp g$ (already edited correspondingly)

Answer (score 1):

You have that $P\subseteq{C^1}$ (where P is the subspace of polinimials defined on $[0,1]$). And this subspace is dense in $C$, so $C^1$ is dense in $C$ too (by stone-weierstrass theorem). with this you can conclude that $(C^1)^{\perp}=\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my edit.